# Duplicidad de contenido en @section('content') que hereda de master template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Tengo un proyecto iniciado con *laravel (8.x)* y tengo un problema con extender la **`master.blade.php`**.

Me explico:

Tengo por ejemplo la siguiente **`master.blade.php`**:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
           @yield('content')
        </div>
         <footer class="row">
        @include('layouts.footer')
    </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Luego tengo una vista que extiende la master template:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

 HOLA

@stop
```

El final de la sección he probado con @stop y con @endsection.

El problema es que ese HOLA/lo que sea que tenga la blade se visualiza 2 veces en la renderización, y la única forma de que no ocurra es quitar el @yield de la master blade, pero no me vale porque necesito obviamente que toda la info vaya dentro del div container. Es decir se printan 2 HOLA...

Para puntualizar la duplicidad de la info existe porque esta se renderiza en el div container, luego el @yield('content') funciona correctamente pero se vuelve a renderizar en otro div más (en ese caso main class="py-4") y no entiendo porque genera este div cuando solo debería printarse dentro del container.

¿Alguna idea de porque puede ocurrir esto?

Comment: Podrías colocar el código de la vista layouts.app? o mejor, porqué estás extendiendo 2 vistas.?

Comment: Hola, ya encontré la solución, bueno más bien el problema. Había 2 @yields('section') uno en el layouts app y otro en el master, no me había dado cuenta.